# Simple web based file browser with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I made a simple web-based file browser with Flask. It also shows some metadata of a file. I have a few questions regarding security though. Is it possible for an attacker to escape out of the preset root directory? Are there any ways to make my code more readable and/or more efficient? Would love to hear some feedback to improve my program! :)

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
import stat

app = Flask(__name__)

# Make the WSGI interface available at the top level so wfastcgi can get it.
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

FILE_SYSTEM_ROOT = "D:\Test123"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/browser')
def browse():
    itemList = os.listdir(FILE_SYSTEM_ROOT)
    return render_template('browse.html', itemList=itemList)

@app.route('/browser/<path:urlFilePath>')
def browser(urlFilePath):
    nestedFilePath = os.path.join(FILE_SYSTEM_ROOT, urlFilePath)
    if os.path.isdir(nestedFilePath):
        itemList = os.listdir(nestedFilePath)
        fileProperties = {"filepath": nestedFilePath}
        if not urlFilePath.startswith("/"):
            urlFilePath = "/" + urlFilePath
        return render_template('browse.html', urlFilePath=urlFilePath, itemList=itemList)
    if os.path.isfile(nestedFilePath):
        fileProperties = {"filepath": nestedFilePath}
        sbuf = os.fstat(os.open(nestedFilePath, os.O_RDONLY)) #Opening the file and getting metadata
        fileProperties['type'] = stat.S_IFMT(sbuf.st_mode) 
        fileProperties['mode'] = stat.S_IMODE(sbuf.st_mode) 
        fileProperties['mtime'] = sbuf.st_mtime 
        fileProperties['size'] = sbuf.st_size 
        if not urlFilePath.startswith("/"):
            urlFilePath = "/" + urlFilePath
        return render_template('file.html', currentFile=nestedFilePath, fileProperties=fileProperties)
    return 'something bad happened'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

browse.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for item in itemList %}
        <li><a href="/browser{{ urlFilePath }}/{{ item }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

file.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Current file: {{ currentFile }}</p>
    <p>
        <table>
            {% for key, value in fileProperties.items() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output when browsing looks something like this:
[image: browse.html example]

The output with the metadata of a file looks like this:
[image: file.html example]

Comment: Food for thoughts: what would happen if I browsed to `htrp://localhost/browser/../an/other/path.txt`?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthias has already mentioned this in the comments, and he is correct.

The code suffers from a Directory Traversal vulnerability

You can filter this in 2 ways:

1. Use `os.path.realpath` and check if the resolved path is different

   ```
   def check_lfi(file_path):
       return os.path.realpath(file_path) != file_path
   ```
2. Use regex to filter out bad (`../`) Paths

   ```
   import re
   DIR_TRAVERSAL = re.compile(r"\.\.\/")
   def check_lfi(file_path):
       return bool(DIR_TRAVERSAL.search(file_path))
   ```

My advice would be to use the first example, since blacklisting can be error prone *(Unicode for instance)*

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I updated my original post with the fix. I tested it out with curl and directory traversals aren't possible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code with the feedback from Ludiposed. This is what it looks like:

```
@app.route('/browser/<path:urlFilePath>')
def browser(urlFilePath):
    nestedFilePath = os.path.join(FILE_SYSTEM_ROOT, urlFilePath)
    nestedFilePath = nestedFilePath.replace("/", "\\")
    if os.path.realpath(nestedFilePath) != nestedFilePath:
        return "no directory traversal please."
    if os.path.isdir(nestedFilePath):
        itemList = os.listdir(nestedFilePath)
        fileProperties = {"filepath": nestedFilePath}
        if not urlFilePath.startswith("/"):
            urlFilePath = "/" + urlFilePath
        return render_template('browse.html', urlFilePath=urlFilePath, itemList=itemList)
    if os.path.isfile(nestedFilePath):
        fileProperties = {"filepath": nestedFilePath}
        sbuf = os.fstat(os.open(nestedFilePath, os.O_RDONLY)) #Opening the file and getting metadata
        fileProperties['type'] = stat.S_IFMT(sbuf.st_mode) 
        fileProperties['mode'] = stat.S_IMODE(sbuf.st_mode) 
        fileProperties['mtime'] = sbuf.st_mtime 
        fileProperties['size'] = sbuf.st_size 
        if not urlFilePath.startswith("/"):
            urlFilePath = "/" + urlFilePath
        return render_template('file.html', currentFile=nestedFilePath, fileProperties=fileProperties)
    return 'something bad happened'
```

I changed some things:

- The forward slashes get replaced by backward slahes, since i'm developing in a Windows enviroment.
- The canonical filepath should be the same as the requested filepath, this filters out ../ and other directory traversal methods from the url.
- The new code has been tested with curl, and is safe.